# How to resolve the issue of two sequences converging to zero for $n, m \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

My question is motivated by the following exercise in probability theory:

> Let $X_n \to X$ in probability and $X_n \geq Y$ a.s. Show that  $X \geq Y$ a.s.

I noticed that for all $n, m \in  \mathbb N$: $$P(X < Y) \leq P\left(|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{m}\right) + P\left(X_n < Y+\frac{1}{m}\right)$$

so for the two terms on the RHS holds:
$$\forall m \in  \mathbb N: \ P\left(|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{m}\right) \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty$$
$$\forall n \in  \mathbb N: \ P\left(X_n<Y+\frac{1}{m}\right)\to 0 \text{ as } m\to \infty$$

Is there a way to finish the proof from this point?

Note that I'm not asking for a proof of the statement (I've seen another one where the issue doesn't come up).

Comment: Why are you trying to prove that $\mathbf{P}(X\leq Y) = 0$?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want your statement to say something like $P(X \geq Y) \leq P(|X_n - X| > 1/m) + P(X_n > Y + 1/m)$.  I hope that $P(X_n < Y + 1/m)$ doesn't go to zero because that makes it hard to believe $X_n \leq Y$ a.s.

Comment: @Nocturne: thanks, I've fixed the statement.

Comment: @muaddib: I messed up the signs in the statement, hopefully, it makes sense now.

Comment: @Leo Assuming your inequality is true for all $m$ and $n$, you can easily finish the proof. Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Choose an $n$ sufficiently large so that the first term at the RHS is less than $\epsilon/2$ and then an $m$ sufficiently large such that the second term is less than $\epsilon/2$. That proves that $\mathbf{P}(X<Y) \leq \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, i.e. $\mathbf{P}(X<Y) = 0$.

Comment: @Nocturne: but to say "Choose an $n$ sufficiently large so that the first term at the RHS is less than $ϵ/2$" we should already have an $m$ fixed, right? And for the second term it's the other way around.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375128/does-convergence-in-probability-preserve-the-weak-inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a small change: Instead of $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)$ consider $\mathbb{P}(X+2/m \leq Y)$. Then, by a very similar argumentation, we find

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}\left(X+2/m \leq Y \right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X+2/m \leq Y, |X_n-X| \leq \frac{1}{m} \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( X+2/m \leq Y, |X_n-X| > \frac{1}{m} \right) \\ &\leq \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(X_n < Y) }_{0}+ \mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| > \frac{1}{m}). \end{align*}$$

Now let $n \to \infty$ and then $m \to \infty$ to conclude that

$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X+2/m \leq Y) = 0.$$